# from MySql database to embedded database?

Tags: java, mysql, database

i made a javafx application using MySql database , and now i want to use an embedded database.

whitch do you think is most similar to mysql , because i don't want to change too much in my program "queries".

Comment: You can try H2 or apache Derby embedded databases

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

For basic SELECTs and most CRUD operations is the same as any SQL server-based engine.